# In the spring tool suite, we added maven dependencies using pom.xml, but the shape is different as shown in the picture, why is that?

Tags: java, maven

In the spring tool suite, we added maven dependencies using pom.xml, but the shape is different as shown in the picture, why is that?
Depends on the version of the library.
I'm really curious.

Thank you for reading it.

**Spring tool suite library image**

[image: reference]

Answer (score 2):

It is in the shape of a jar to represent that its a jar file. When it is shaped like a paper, it means that your jar just had machine code in it. Compared to the other jar files that are shaped like a jar, they contain .class files with Java code in it.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer.
But when I opened and compared the javassist-3.4.GA.jar file with the json-20070929.jar file, why does the abc file exist in both libraries?

Comment: I'm sorry you need to be more specific about what you mean by "abc file".

Comment: sorry, abc -> .class file

Comment: I think it was a bug in the Eclipse system. The place where my JAR file looked like a piece of paper and contained machine code isn't like that anymore. It is a normal class file. To explain what I think is a bug into more detail, when you double clicked on it to open, it would actually crash your Eclipse for a few seconds but then open up the lengthy machine code. Compared to a normal JAR file, it will just simply open up all the packages that are contained in the JAR file with the .class files which contain Java code.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to you, I could understand.